# Calculating lattice thermal conductivity using Quantum ESPRESSO and phonopy

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, physical-properties-of-materials, phonopy, thermal

How should I calculate lattice thermal conductivity in Quantum ESPRESSO? I have installed phonopy. My Linux distribution is Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm kind of new to this, but from what I've read you might need to use the ShengBTE code along with QE in order to find the lattice thermal conductivity.

Comment: @AnoopANair yes. That’s what I will be trying to solve this. If I get it done successfully, I will post the steps here after as answer to this problem.

Comment: @epsilon02fft Did you have any luck?

Comment: @NikeDattani Yes I did. I was successful in performing phonopy and phono3py calculations for Si. The codes ran successfully, but I am facing further problems of mpirun and RAM limitations about which I will post soon. Apologies for not responding before, couldn’t login to my account and also got busy with uni official work.

Answer (score 3):

Some years ago I found the following steps in [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_could_we_find_thermal_conductivity_using_Phonon_band_structure_Particularly_step_by_step_using_Quantum_Espresso):
You need:

- [QuantumEspresso](http://www.quantum-espresso.org/) (QE)
- [Phono3py](https://phonopy.github.io/phono3py/)
- [ShengBTE & thirdorder.py](https://www.shengbte.org/home)

> - First, you need to create a QE input file (`pwscf`), using `ibrav=0`,
>   lattice vectors in bohr units, atomic coordinates in crystal units.
> - Using the input file, run `phono3py/third_order.py` to create supercell
>   within finite displacement method.
> - Then you need to write a script
>   that will copy all header option, specially `&control` and `&system` to
>   each supercell file and rename to `scf.in` and generate sequential
>   folder namely, `disp-00001`..., ect.
> - Now run `pwscf` for each supercell and
>   please do not forget to select force calculation in `pwscf` input file.
> - After this step you need to run `phono3py` to calculate second order
>   (harmonic) and third order (anharmonic) force constants.
> - Finally, run `phono3py` to calculate lattice thermal conductivity using dense q-point grid and primitive cell.

Comment: Thank you sir for your reply. I was successful to run these codes. Now I am working to solve ShengBTE code and the problem I am facing of mpirun which is occurring in 3rd step above (as your wrote)

Answer (score 1):

there is this D3Q package that works seamlessly with Quantum Espresso.

I used it in several papers such as PRB 98, 220301(R) (2018). Easier than the QE-phonopy-shengbte chain. Quite demanding computationally, though.

https://anharmonic.github.io

G Fugallo et al., PRB 88, 045430 (2013)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, recently I got to know about D3Q package and I have started reading its manual as well as practice sample examples.